# Installing npm modules in a VM shared directory and grunt issues

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, vmware

I'm trying to put together a development environment and npm is causing me problems. Here is my scenario:

I have a development machine running Windows and VMWare Player. I have a Ubuntu Server VM (no UI) which is configured with Apache, PHP, NodeJS etc. As the VM has no UI I want to use the host OS for development. I set up a shared directory which in the VM is accessed as /mnt/hgfs/source/<project name>.

The problem comes when I attempt to run `npm install` within this directory. I see a lot of errors like `Error: UNKNOWN, symlink '../requirejs/bin/r.js'`. I know that my package.json file is OK because if I copy all files out of the share and into a regular unix directory (/var/www/<project name>) `npm install` works fine. So npm has a problem installing modules in the shared directory.

I thought I could get around this by installing the node packages globally but, for whatever reason, the GruntJS enthusiasts [don't like that](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-cli/issues/10) and it must be present locally. I then tried to create an npm link from global to local but that just results in a new error: `Error: May not delete: /usr/lib/node_modules/grunt`. I have full permissions on the /usr/lib/node_modules directory and all sub-directories.

I really don't want to write the entire project using a command-line text editor in the VM but it looks like I cannot have my code-base in a directory available to both the host and guest OS through VMWare.

I would very much appreciate any suggestions on how to either 1) allow npm modules to be installed in my shared directory, 2) run Grunt globally, or 3) solve the npm link error I'm seeing.

**EDIT**: Shortly after posting this I realised the fundamental issue here - it's not possible to create symbolic links within a VM shared directory when the host OS is Windows. As npm install uses symlinks by default it didn't work, and this is why the accepted solution does work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
npm install --no-bin-links
```

Grunt should be local since the plugins and `gruntfile.js` may require a certain version of Grunt in order to run your tasks. If another developer would like to run your tasks, they could just issue an `npm install` and they are set. (See [this](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation) for more info.) `grunt-cli` is global which is used to run the local version of `grunt`

Comment: Perfect! `--no-bin-links` did the trick thanks. I'm already fully sold on the merits of installing the modules locally but that just wasn't possible with my previous approach. All good now though.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to allow the VM to create links. I don't know for VMWare, but as I ended up on this topic looking for the same issue under VirtualBox, here's my solution for this software.

Say your VM is labelled `MyVM` and your shared directory is labelled `myshared`. Then type this in your console:

```
VBoxManage setextradata MyVM VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/myshared 1
```

Reboot your VirtualBox's VM and you're good!