# npm install Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../mkdirp/bin/cmd.js'

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, fat32

Still failed even after reinstall node and npm.
Here is the full error message

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.8.0-34-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/lt1pchanifa/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.3/bin/node" "/home/lt1pchanifa/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.3/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.9.3
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5
npm ERR! path ../mkdirp/bin/cmd.js
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! syscall symlink

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../mkdirp/bin/cmd.js' -> '/media/lt1pchanifa/B0D0-8B34/Edwin/thinkster-ng2/node_modules/@angular-cli/ast-tools/node_modules/.bin/mkdirp'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../mkdirp/bin/cmd.js' -> '/media/lt1pchanifa/B0D0-8B34/Edwin/thinkster-ng2/node_modules/@angular-cli/ast-tools/node_modules/.bin/mkdirp'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -1,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../mkdirp/bin/cmd.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/media/lt1pchanifa/B0D0-8B34/Edwin/thinkster-ng2/node_modules/@angular-cli/ast-tools/node_modules/.bin/mkdirp',
npm ERR!   parent: '@angular-cli/ast-tools' }
```

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5824 Are you trying to install in an NTFS Partition from linux?

Comment: @suraj no, it's FAT32

Comment: So its a Windows partition..I think it is the same issue as suggested in the github link.. you should try in your linux home folder which would be EXT4

Answer (score 28):

You are trying to run `npm` in a linux platform within a Windows FAT32 folder.

```
/media/lt1pchanifa/B0D0-8B34/Edwin/thinkster-ng2
```

According to  [github issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5824), permission problems occur while trying to access Windows partition.
Try to move the project to Home directory which is EXT4 and run the command.

Comment: my home's partition is short on free space, unless this is the only solution I will resize my partition then

Comment: I am not sure it will work otherwise. The filesystems are different. Linux permissions are incompatible with windows file systems

Comment: Thanks for the answer, saved me a lot of time debuggein that strange error. Would say it sounds like a bug though.

Comment: Thank you @SurajRao I really appreciate your post. I could not work it out no matter what I tried. FAT32 permissions were the problem.

Comment: This also seems to happen with exfat.

Answer (score 10):

I haven't tried this myself but maybe you could skip creating symlinks if it's only problem with them.

`npm install --no-bin-links`

See more here:

- [npm install: when to use --no-bin-links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39098812/npm-install-when-to-use-no-bin-links)
- [Installing npm modules in a VM shared directory and grunt issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983923/installing-npm-modules-in-a-vm-shared-directory-and-grunt-issues)

Comment: This worked for Linux. Thanks!